# asp.net C# Rdlc Report Sum #Error in column

Tags: c#, asp.net

Dear all coder please help me with this, I am having a column of student marks in my report and the row of the columns contains both Number as mark and Text as Grade. So when I sum the total of the column it throws an error #Error, where as when I replaced the Text or grade from the row as a number then it gives the correct result. But I want it to give the sum even when it contains the Text in the row, it should only calculate the Number and avoid Text. 
Please Help Me!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0IXP.png)

Comment: You'll need to show your code if you want help with it :)

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy first of all thanks for atleast turning to my problem. Well here is the code that I used in the Expression :=Sum(int(Fields!FirstSecond.Value))

Comment: Need a bit more that that, edit your question and show the full code. What language is this? It isn't c#

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy Sorry if my ways of question is not proper. Yes it is in C# asp.net web application and I am making rdlc report where I have a table dataset and have a column with Marks to be sum at the end of the row. And in the row field I am using Expression builder to calculate auto sum and the expression is  =Sum(int(Fields!FirstSecond.Value))

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy Also could you please see the picture I have attached. Please need help.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do something like Sum( IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!FieldName.Value) = 1, Fields!FieldName.Value, 0)). Not tested just suggestion

Comment: @Hakunamatata Okay let me try. Thanks!!

Comment: @Hakunamatata I tried this : =Sum( IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!FirstSecond.Value) = 1, Fields!FirstSecond.Value, 0))  It doesn’t show error now but gives result as 0. Please guide me further.

Comment: @DharamRai and it worked or not ?

Comment: @Hakunamatata It doesn’t show error now but gives result as 0. Please guide me further.

Comment: @DharamRai Try this  Sum(IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!FirstSecond.Value), CInt(Fields!FirstSecond.Value), 0))

Comment: @Hakunamatata now when the marks rows contain only number then it shows the correct result but since my marks rows also contain text as Grade (A, B) for some subject then it shows #Error. It works only for number but not when the rows also contain text. :( No Luck, Could you save me with this please..

Comment: @DharamRai I think that is because SSRS IIF evaluates both true and false expression no matter what IIf condition  evaluates to. Try  Sum(CInt(IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!FirstSecond.Value), Fields!FirstSecond.Value, 0)))

Comment: @Hakunamatata Wow!!! It worked Thank you Life Saver, had been beating my head since yesterday.. Thanks a Ton Life Saver :)

Comment: @DharamRai I posted my comment as answer. You should be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer from my above comment. It may be helpful to someone. SSRS IIF evaluates both true and false expression no matter what IIf condition evaluates to so casting needs to be done after IIF evaluates.

```
   =Sum(CInt(IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!FirstSecond.Value), Fields!FirstSecond.Value, 0)))
```